# Cannot set background image in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I'm having this issue with Visual Studio and it's driving me crazy. I just can't figure out what's wrong here. Here's the problem. I just cannot set background image in VS2010. So, I created my html page using File -> New Project -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application. I included link on that page to the CSS page. Went to source page and put my pointer in body tag. Returned to Design page and selected Apply New Style. Selector is set to body, defined in existing style sheet and selected the URL to the CSS file. Went Background -> Background image and with browse selected my image. X and Y background position is sent to center. After that, I hit Apply and OK. Now, in Visual Studio, background image is set and I can see it. Also, I went to the CSS file and there is a body defined style. So, Visual Studio is showing it and its also specified in CSS file. However, when I save and hit F5 it doesn't show on web browser. Anyone, please, help me, I'm hard stuck with this. Here's the HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="Styles/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <table class="style1">
        <tr>
            <td>
                SITE NAME</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="instruction.htm">Instruction</a><a href="author.htm">Author</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS:

```css
body
{
    background-image: url('../background.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
}
```

And here's the image from inside Visual Studio showing that I'm seeing the background in here (don't mind the picture, something farm related xD):
[Visual Studio Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgeq9.jpg)

Comment: We'd need to see the actual CSS and HTML produced by the designer. Just telling us what you didn't doesn't actually constitute the full story.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll link you project here. https://ufile.io/nl1r8

Comment: Any relevant code needs to be within the question itself, please. External links can change or disappear, making the question useless to future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Use the "edit" button to change your question, and only include what's actually needed to demonstrate the problem, not your entire project. Also, if you don't mind, I have no intention of downloading a random RAR file from a stranger off a random site onto my PC :-)

Comment: Ye, sure thing xD, I'll do it right away.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xh68aeoy/ - in theory your code works. Difficult to know what the issue is, other than maybe the path to the image is wrong. Check in your browser's network tab when running the project to see whether it loads the file or not

Answer (score 1):

You should place the image in the current path of the project, along with your own aspx file or in a folder inside your project
some thing like this 
g:/myASPNETproject/myASPNETproject/WebForm1.aspx // your webpage

g:/myASPNETproject/myASPNETproject/background.jpg

```
body
{
    background-image: url('background.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
}
```

or

g:/myASPNETproject/myASPNETproject/images/background.jpg

```
   body
  {
    background-image: url('images/background.jpg');
    background-position: center center;
  }
```

Comment: "does not have the ability to access the file backwards" Can you clarify what you mean by this? It doesn't seem to be any kind of technical term. Also the URL in the CSS property should absolutely **not** be a file path on disk (e.g. G:\) - it should be something accessible via HTTP. Doing it with a disk path will never work when deployed to a server.

Comment: Why suggest something which only works in debug mode? OP will only be disappointed when they deploy. I agree you also suggested about placing the file in a location which is part of the project, which is sensible, but it was combined with bad advice which you still haven't removed.

Comment: " Written when debugging"...So? No-one writes code just for debugging, the intention is always to make it go live somehow, otherwise what's the point? My comment has nothing to do with ethics and is about getting correct information onto the answer. Should I leave incorrect information when I see it , to mislead the OP? Is _that_ ethical? We could debate it but we won't, on this forum anyway. At least you changed it and this is now a much better answer - thanks.

Comment: Thank you guys for trying to help me out on this issue. Unfortunately I wasn't able to solve the problem but I ran into some weird "solutions". Using the same method I described above, on random times I'm able to set background image. So, it can work but its not guaranteed. Also, I tried few times to undo setting background (after setting it and bg not showing) and then do it again, guess what, it worked. After trying this out few times, it looks like this "solution" is random as well. If someone finds solutions, please post it here. Until then, spam until u make it right :D